# Automating/Scraping html from C# - redirects and logins/logouts

Tags: c#, html, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to scrape a web app that uses a few redirects and logouts/logins in between requests. I believe I'll have to set AllowAutoRedirect to false so I can capture the redirect requests and manually redirect while watching for new cookies. My only experience with cookies is to just set the container and forget about it... do I have to parse the response headers to decide actions to take with cookies? Can someone lay out a general approach?

**Update**
It turns out that Chris was right. The redirects and cookies were working just fine... the application I was hitting did not like that I was not setting all the right headers (content type, user agent). After adding those in, I'm getting the response I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the `CookieContainer` part right which most people miss so kudos to you!

`AllowAutoRedirect` should pick up cookies as redirects happen. Is there a reason that you need to manually process things?

Comment: I'm just guessing that my cookies are not being set properly. After a certain request, I receive 2 302 redirects. I'm not receiving the response that I receive via my browser, so I'm trying to find out why. The first redirect sends me to a logout page, and the second redirect sends me to another login page. This all works as one request in the browser, but it is not working via my HttpWebRequest calls. I can clean up and share some of the request/response headers that firebug reports if you think that will help.